# Hibernate : Generate a number for an integer column (not primary key)

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, sequence

Is it possible to generate a number for a column that is not a primary key? There is the `@GeneratedValue` for generating ids, but I'm not certain if I can use it for usual columns as well.

Comment: what format or length should that have this column? And how do you want to added the values to this column?

Comment: it should just be a number, and I don't want to explicitly add the value, I want it to be generated

Comment: you can generate a random number and add this one by persisting the object. Something like: Entity e; e.setColumn(randomNumber);

Comment: the number needs to be sequential, otherwise I cannot make use of it

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `@GeneratedValue` only works for identifiers, so the best practice here is to go for a database sequence for the respective column, at least that is what i think.

Hope it helps! Cheers!